# How to upgrade a Deployment in Helm without modifying replicas?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hpa

When creating a `Deployment` and `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` together in a Helm chart, should the deployment’s `.spec.replicas` be set to `null`, or should it be unset, or should it be set to some value between the hpa’s `minReplicas` and `maxReplicas`?

When you create a hpa, the hpa controller manages the deployment’s `.spec.replicas`, so when you update the deployment’s other fields you shouldn’t change the replicas.

Comparing to `kubectl apply` declarative config, you can modify other fields of the deployment without modifying `.spec.replicas` if you leave `.spec.replicas` unset the first time the deployment is created, so that the 3-way diff ignores that field when the deployment is applied in the future. Or to omit the field after creation time, you have to use `kubectl apply edit-last-applied` to avoid accidentally scaling down to 1 when removing the field ([kubernetes/kubernetes#67135](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67135)). So with `kubectl apply` it is possible to apply a deployment while not touching `.spec.replicas`.

What is the correct way to `helm upgrade` a deployment’s other fields without changing its scaling?

Comment: Hi @yonran, I checked [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090) and If I understand correctly there are 2 ways of doing that. First would be to add if statement  as mentioned [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090#issuecomment-605682145). Second would be to  simply  remove  replicas field completely, then it should respect the replicas number managed by HPA, there is [comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090#issuecomment-605759355) about it. Could you check above comments and let me know if that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I checked [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090) and If I understand correctly there are 2 ways of doing that.

1.Add if statement as a workaround.

There is comment about it added by @naseemkullah.

> so the workaround is to add an if statement around the deployment's spec.replicas to not template it if HPA is enabled

---

2.Remove replicas field completely, then it should respect the replicas number managed by HPA.

There is [comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090#issuecomment-605870466) about it added by @tianchengli.

> If I remove replicas field completely, it will respect the replicas number managed by HPA.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your two actual questions:

1. When using an HPA, *don't* set a `replicas` field in your Deployment or StatefulSet. Leave it out. When helm renders your Deployment template during `helm upgrade` and patches the Deployment object in Kubernetes, the `replicas` field will not be part of the patch and the existing field will be left alone (it will continue being managed by the HPA controller).
2. The correct way to manage the Deployment's remaining fields with Helm is to simply create a normal Helm template per usual, sans the `replicas` field as stated above.

If you initially specify a `replicas` field in the Helm template and deploy it, and also configure an HPA to autoscale the Deployment, you will run into a nasty situation as described in [Helm issue #7090](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090) when you attempt to *remove* or otherwise modify the `replicas` field in the template. [I left a comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7090#issuecomment-1877520534) describing how to safely escape and correct this when desperate (by manually editing the Helm release object), but it's a bit involved. Cheers.